# Why does my associated object not save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

(Rails Newbie here) I have two models Usuario and Ficha. Usuario has a has_one association with Ficha.

Here are my models:

```
class Ficha < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :usuario
end

class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :ficha, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Here is the Usuario Controller:

```
    class UsuariosController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      def index
        @usuarios = Usuario.all
        @usuario_last = Usuario.last(10)
        @usuario_rev = @usuario_last.reverse
        @user_count = current_user.usuarios

        #Search
        @usuario_search = if params[:term]
          Usuario.where("name ~* ?", params[:term])
        else
          Usuario.all
        end
        @usuario_pag = @usuario_search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
      end

      def show
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @usuario = current_user.usuarios.build
      end

      def create
        @usuario = current_user.usuarios.build(usuario_params)

        @usuario.save
        redirect_to @usuario
      end

      def edit
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])

        if @usuario.update(usuario_params)
          redirect_to @usuario
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:id])
        @usuario.destroy

      redirect_to usuarios_path
      end

      private
        def usuario_params
          params.require(:usuario).permit(:name, :age, :doc, :docnum, :estadocivil, :country, :street,
          :direction, :municipal, :zipcode, :tel1, :tel2)
        end
    end
```

Here is my Ficha Controller:

```
    class FichasController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      def index
      end

      def show
        @ficha = Ficha.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:usuario_id])
        if @usuario.ficha.nil?
          @ficha = @usuario.build_ficha
        else
          flash[:error] = "Ya tienes una ficha"
        end
      end

      def create
        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:usuario_id])

        @ficha = @usuario.build_ficha(ficha_params)
        if @ficha.save
          redirect_to @usuario, :notice => "Your ficha has been successfully created."
        else
          render :action => 'new'
        end
      end

      def edit
        #@ficha = Ficha.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @ficha = Ficha.find(params[:id])

            if @ficha.update(ficha_params)
                redirect_to @ficha
            else
                render 'edit'
            end
      end

      def destroy

        @usuario = Usuario.find(params[:usuario])
        @ficha = @usuario.fichas.find(params[:id])
        @ficha.destroy

      redirect_to fichas_path
    end

    private
      def ficha_params
        params.require(:ficha).permit(:name, :age, :doc, :docnum, :estadocivil, :country, :street,
        :direction, :municipal, :zipcode, :tel1, :tel2, :time, :redes, :estudios, :profession,
        :laboral, :discapacity, :percent, :derivado1, :derivado2, :derivacion, :nombredelprofesional,
        :observaciones, :conocio, :signature, :date, :term)
      end
    end
```

Am I going wrong somewhere with the creation of the ficha in the controller? Would it be better to create the object right after with after_create in the usuario model?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're going about this the right way. If your `@ficha` object isn't saving, it's likely because of validation errors, or not being associated properly.

Check out [debugging with the console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#console) command to learn how you can troubleshoot these types of problems, by inserting a `console` after your save attempt to see if there are any errors attached to your `@ficha` object.

> Web Console is a bit like byebug, but it runs in the browser. In any
>   page you are developing, you can request a console in the context of a
>   view or a controller. The console would be rendered next to your HTML
>   content.
>   4.1 Console
>
> Inside any controller action or view, you can invoke the console by
>   calling the console method.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.2.1

Here i don't see that you use 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'. Read about that http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Try these

```
class Ficha < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :usuario
end

class Usuario < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_one :ficha, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :ficha
end
```

and also you have permit ficha_attributs in UsuariosController like these

```
private
  def usuario_params
     params.require(:usuario).permit(:name, :age, :doc, :docnum, :estadocivil, :country, :street,:direction, :municipal, :zipcode, :tel1, :tel2, ficha_attributes: [# Write ficha attributes you want save])
  end
```